# How can I achieve this layout using CSS only?

Tags: css, html, layout

[image: layout]

I am trying to build a layout that has two div blocks next to each other. Both of them are centered to the page. The left block (1) varies in width depending on how much space their is available in the window (from 300px min to 400px max). Block 2 has a fixed width of 640px and does not change. Both block's height extend to the bottom of the page. If one block is longer than the other than the other block would compensate with white space (with the background color still applied).

Youtube's video page can be used as an example, however in my case the larger block is on the right. Notice how youtube's right block (suggested videos) gets larger or smaller from 300-400px when the window is resized.

This is the best I can come with:

http://jsfiddle.net/7dL5z/

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width:1040px;
    min-width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;  
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:400px;
    height:100%;
    background:#EEE;
}

#right {
    float:right;
    width:640px;
    height:100%;
    background:#666;    
}

<html>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left">left</div>
      <div id="right">right</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Two problems:

1) I can't get the divs to extend to the bottom.

2) Adding a float to block 1 renders the min-width property useless

I am looking for a JS and CSS media query free solution if possible.

Any one have a clue?

Comment: Do you care about browser support? This could be done using `display: table-cell`.

Comment: Yes, I would want majority of browsers to support it.

Comment: Well, you need to define "majority of browsers" for you. `display: table` and its counterparts (e.g. `table-cell`) are [supported in many browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-table), including back to IE8. If you don't need to support farther back than IE8, then table display CSS rules are fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

You need to add

```
html {
height:100%;
}
```

to get html's sub elements to fit the window. Then remove `height:auto` from the `wrapper`.

If you have a max-width set in pixels on the wrapper without telling it a variable width relative to the window (like `width:90%`), the contents can't change size when the browser resizes, because their width is fixed.

So I added `width:90%` for demo purposes. You can set it to whatever percentage you think looks nice in the window.

Put your `right` div before your `left` in your html like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="right">right</div>
    <div id="left">left</div>
</div>
```

and then you can use `left` to fill the space left by `right` without having to float it or tell it a width. Setting the max & min width on the wrapper will keep `left` from getting too small or big.

So the final css would be:

```
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;  
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
max-width:1040px;
min-width:940px;
margin:0 auto;  
height: 100%;
width:90%;
}

#left {
overflow:hidden;
height:100%;
background:#EEE;
}

#right {
float:right;
width:640px;
height:100%;
background:#666;    
}
```

Comment: Awesome! A solution without needing to use display:table I find better

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8T4x/), pretty nifty solution, and I would guess is compatible with much older IE versions since it doesn't use `display: table`.

Comment: The only big problem I am having with this is that content inside the blocks tend to escape the right block, and content in the left one is hidden due to overflow:hidden (if the content exceeds the height)

Comment: You could set it to `overflow-x:hidden` instead to only hide the horizontal content and allow it to scroll vertically. I haven't tried it with content yet, but if you set a width on the content too, it would probably solve it.

Comment: Any way to get a absolute bottom footer (footer that always stays on the bottom regardless of the height of the blocks) to work with this layout?

Comment: put a footer div within the wrapper and i would set the height of the columns to whatever percentage would add up to 100 with the footer, so that the content doesn't go under the footer.`#footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1040px;
    background:blue;
    height:2%;
    }`

Comment: since i've solved not one, but three, problems for you now, i'd appreciate you accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it using `display: table-cell`.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;  
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    min-width: 940px;
}

#left {
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 400px;
    background:#EEE;
}

#right {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 640px;
    height: 100%;
    background:#666;    
}
```

To get the panels to extent to 100% of the browser height, you need to set the height on the `html` element.

The behavior may be close to what you need.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ZVN97/

Comment: The left block does not seem to be shrinking in width when reducing the size of the window, instead the right block is being pushed towards the right

Comment: @deArtish That's not quite the behavior I'm seeing (Win7, Chrome 31) if I understand what you're describing. When making the page narrower, I see that the left block first starts to reduce from `400px` to `300px` width, while the right block stops moving (and isn't pushed out of view). After the left block hits `300px`, both blocks continue to get pushed off-screen into the right (the left side is anchored to the left side of the screen).

Comment: The left block should reduce in width only when there is no more width available in the window. I'm not noticing any change in the left block's width at all

Comment: @deArtish What browser are you using? It seems to be doing what you are saying you want it to do, for me at least.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. When I am resizing the window the left panel never changes in width

Comment: Huh, that's interesting, it definitely changes width for me in Chrome.

Comment: Tried it again and it works. Sorry for the confusion. One important property to add is vertical-align:top to both blocks, otherwise the content (child divs) in the blocks will be pushed down

Answer (score 0):

My solution is set **wrapper** to `display: table` & its childs to `display:table-cell`.

Both areas will expand bottom when one of them overflow the screen size. If not, both will expand to bottom (100%).

http://jsfiddle.net/7dL5z/4/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
            <p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p><p>left</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;  
    max-width:700px;
    min-width:500px;
    width: 100%;
}

#left {
    background:#EEE;
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 40%;
}

#right {
    display: table-cell;
    background:#666;    
}
```

Comment: The left panel isn't varying width for me, which is one feature that OP is attempting to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Just set the width to elastic column, and define max & min values. For this, table must have a defined elastic size also (width:100% and max/min widths..)

Comment: Now the right panel is also varying width, when OP wants it to stay a static width regardless of the state of the page/other elements.

Comment: I fixed the right panel varying by width by adding min-width:640px and max-width:640px on it

Comment: A big problem with this solution: when I place a div inside the left bock, everything in the right block gets pushed down to the height of that block

Answer (score 0):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pmj7Z/ maybe?

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;  
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width:1040px;
    min-width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;  
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:400px;
    height:100%;
    background:#EEE;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width:640px;
    height:100%;
    background:#666;    
}
```

Comment: There is a gap between the blocks with this, and the left block does not reduce in width on resize

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, here is my answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
layoutInit();

$(window).resize(function() {
  layoutInit();
});

function layoutInit() {
    // you can also hard code the max-width and min-width in the javascript,
    // following function is used to remove "px" on "1040px"-like strings from CSS
    var pxStriper = function(str) {
        return str.substr(0, str.length - 2);
    }

    // all parameters you need to update the layout:
    var bodyWidth = $("body").width(),
        bodyHeight = $("body").width(),
        wrapperMaxWidth = pxStriper($("#wrapper").css("max-width")),
        wrapperMinWidth = pxStriper($("#wrapper").css("min-width")),
        rightWidth = pxStriper($("#right").css("width"));

    // 3 different situations with width of the body:
    if (bodyWidth <= wrapperMaxWidth && bodyWidth >= wrapperMinWidth) {
        // 1:
        $("#wrapper").css('width', bodyWidth);
        $("#left").css('width', bodyWidth - rightWidth);
    } else {
        if (bodyWidth > wrapperMaxWidth) {
            // 2:
            $("#wrapper").css('width', wrapperMaxWidth);
            $("#left").css('width', wrapperMaxWidth - rightWidth);
        } else {
            // 3:
            $("#wrapper").css('width', wrapperMinWidth);
            $("#left").css('width', wrapperMinWidth - rightWidth);                
        }
    }

    // update the height:
    $("#wrapper").height(bodyHeight)
}});
```